# automatic log out user when someone login another user from one account

Tags: php

can someone help me? I want to automatically log out the user when someone login another user to their account and the page will automatically reload and the user will be logged out and go to the login form. My code below is needed to refresh the page to validate the user session token is equal to the token in the database.

```
if($_SESSION['token'] != $usertoken){
  session_destroy();
  unset($_SESSION['user']);
  header("location: /login");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that if User A is logged in to one browser, and User A logs in to another browser anywhere else then you want the first browser to automatically refresh the page and log out?

Comment: yes that's I mean.

Comment: you need to add `column` in your users table called `last_login` and save on it the current date for logging then every time you check the session for user check if 'last_login' date is different from the one saved in his `session`

Comment: That's going to have several moving parts, making it a bit broad here.  At a high level you'll need to track the logged in users outside of session state so your page can check if the current logged in user matches any other logged in user.  And you'll also need to open a web socket between you server-side code and your client-side code to invoke the page reload and logout.

Comment: I did that but the page needs to refresh by the user to validate the data.

Comment: you can make WebSocket as **David** said before or try to send `ajax` request every 5 seconds, for example, to check it in the background but of course, it is not the best practise i think

Comment: @Joseph SESSION handler wont do the same job ? something like this : https://github.com/j2L4e/PHP-PDO-MySQL-Session-Handler/blob/master/SessionHandler.php destroy old session from database on each login

Comment: If the original user with credentials is trusted, you may not need this functionality you seek. However you could use a session cookie, thats how gmail, outlook, etc works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try WebSockets or Server-Side-Events with PHP.

Here are good examples to set up server side events with JS/PHP:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

So you could check every 5 seconds if a new user has been logged in and log the other user out.