# How can I run a block of PHP code every so often?

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a website where the goal is to have only one session per user, I managed to do this with some validations and adding fields to my DB, then suppose that if the user enters with his username and password in Chrome he can navigate without problem, if the The same user in another browser either Firefox enters with his username and password, in the Chrome session when reloading the page or going to another page directly the session is closed, but what I want to do is log out instantly the moment the other session is started or if it is not possible then that this be done in a certain time so as not to wait for the page to reload or change to another.

This is my PHP code where I have the validation, I investigated that I can do it with ajax, but I don't understand how to do it, someone could guide me on this please. I thank you in advance.

```
$userById = $connection_s->getUsers($_SESSION["id_user"]);
    if ($userById["fecha_acceso"] <> $_SESSION["fecha_acceso"]) {
         echo"<script>location.href='logout.php';</script>";    
    }
```

I don't know what else I could put in code, this is my validation.

Comment: *"I investigated that I can do it with ajax"* - Either that or Web Sockets.  Though in this case I imagine AJAX is the simpler approach for you.  (Keep in mind however that it's *much chattier* over the network with that approach.)  What have you tried and what didn't work?  Where do you make your AJAX request?  What is the response?  You can use `setInterval` to periodically repeat that AJAX request.

Comment: some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435682/automatic-log-out-user-when-someone-login-another-user-from-one-account